# vanilla ruby rspec cannot see my files

Tags: ruby, rspec

So, I am trying to create a gem with a lib folder and a spec folder for rspec tests, like so:

```
- my_gem
|-- lib
| |-- my_gem
| | |-- foo.rb
| |
| |-- my_gem.rb
|
|-- spec
| |-- lib
|   |-- foo_spec.rb
|
|-- my_gem.gemfile
|-- Rakefile
```

my_gem.rb contains `require 'my_gem/foo'` which works fine.

But my spec file which tries to `require 'lib/my_gem'` doesn't work. When I run rspec (or rake spec) without explicitly setting a path with `-I .`, it fails to load the file:

```
foo_spec.rb:1 in `require': cannot load such file -- lib/my_gem.rb (LoadError)
```

I feel like I shouldn't have to require a spec_helper.rb in every spec just to fix this, nor should I have to specify the load path for rspec every time. There has to be a simple convention that I am missing because I am new to gem development (I usually only do rails stuff).

---

Edit: I should point out that I am well aware that I can `require_relative '../../lib/my_gem.rb'`. The point is that I want to be able to get the root folder onto my path automatically like I am used to in rails. If this just isn't possible then please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec doesn't know the path to `lib/my_gem`. Try

```
require_relative '../../lib/my_gem'
```

Comment: Yes, this works, and I had already landed here myself, but it seemed needlessly complex. Doesn't rspec have a way of getting the root folder onto the path automatically?

Comment: How should it know what the "root folder" is? It knows under Rails because it has the Rails environment to lean on, where all the appropriate require paths have been added already. Without Rails, your best best is probably to `require` a `spec_helper` in each spec; that could simply add `../..` to the search path array `$:`